wireguard vpn in gnome-control-center
Wireguard connections were configured using wg-quick, after updating to 24.04 all users got the ability to enable/disable them.
I would like only the administrator to be able to manage wg connections using wg-quick and systemctl.
Maybe someone has figured this out?
